# ActiveStorage - Where should the blobs be placed for active storage fixtures in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing tests for a resource controller I've created. I want to test that the action redirects to the  correct url of the file however I get a `URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): nil` error from my existing fixture setup so I assume I need to have the blobs actually stored somewhere. Any help would be great!

```
class StorageController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionController::Live

  def resource
    filename = "#{params.fetch(:filename)}.#{params.fetch(:format)}"
    resource = Resource.find_by!(name: filename)
    redirect_to resource.file.service_url
  end
end
```

```
require 'test_helper'

class StorageControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "resources redirects to resource" do
    get resource_storage_path(resources(:summary).name)
    assert_redirected_to resources(:summary).file.service_url
  end
end
```

```
#blobs.yml

summary_blob:
  key: aabbWNGW1VrxZ8Eu4zma23ja
  filename: 'summary.pdf'
  content_type: 'application/pdf'
  metadata: '{"identified":true,"analyzed":true}'
  byte_size: <%= File.size('tmp/storage/aa/bb/aabbWNGW1VrxZ8Eu4zma23ja') %>
  checksum: <%= Digest::MD5.file('tmp/storage/aa/bb/aabbWNGW1VrxZ8Eu4zma23ja').base64digest %>
  created_at: <%= DateTime.now %>
```

```
#attachments.yml

summary_attachment:
  name: file
  record: summary (Resource)
  blob: summary_blob
  created_at: <%= DateTime.now %>
```

```
#resources.yml

summary:
  name: 2019_event_summary.pdf
```